# Google maps crash: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array

Tags: android, google-maps

I see a lot of following crashes in `Crashlytics`:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.g.a(g.java:56)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.ao.a(ao.java:91)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.store.fetch.i.a(i.java:99)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.store.fetch.f.a(f.java:3)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.store.j.a(j.java:19)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.store.k.a(k.java:96)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.store.f.handleMessage(f.java:71)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.store.k.run(k.java:126)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.store.ab.run(ab.java:12)
```

All of them happen on Android 5, mostly on Lenovo devices.

The map is loaded in `SupportMapFragment`.

Dependencies (current latest):

`com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0`

`com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.6.2`

What could be the cause of this crash?

Comment: you are trying to get item from ArrayList which is null, there's nothing with map here, please add more code

Comment: @Oussema Aroua I will check it, but I don't think that is related to my code. In the stacktrace there is no mention of any class from my app. Also, why is it that the crash only happening on some Android 5 devices? If there was be a problem with the `List` initialization wouldn't it crash on other devices too? I think, it would be helpful to find out which `ArrayList` the class `com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.g.a` is using and what is the purpose of it.

Comment: @AlexeyTimokhin does the problem remain after updating mapUtils version?

Comment: Seems the bug is already filed on the official issuetracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145941832

So i would not say this issue is not fucused ;). Thanx for posting this question.

Comment: @Yaroslav, yes, the problem remains after updating mapUtils.

Comment: Why this is closed?

Comment: @Mladen Rakonjac It was closed by other users: "This question needs to be more focused." You can vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok, so I opened a ticket on google issue tracker and a lot of people confirmed they were facing the same crash.

Seems like an internal bug ticket was created and the work is being done to resolve the issue on maps side. 
Also a temporary workaround was suggested in [comments](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145941832#comment12):

> The workaround, that worked for me is to set maxZoomPreference on the
>   map equal to 16 and to use 16 as zoom level in the calling of the
>   newLatLngZoom method. It seems that the issue occurs only when you try
>   to zoom more than 16 levels.

We implemented the suggested approach in our app and it indeed prevents the crash.

**Upd:**

According to Google the crash was fixed for future SDK versions.

> Upon further checking, our Engineering Team was able to reproduce the
>   problem and already fixed it in the latest SDK version.

Answer (score 5):

I faced with this problem on Lenovo TB3-710I (android 5.1). The workaround was disabling 3D model buildings.

```
googleMap.isBuildingsEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Still an issue with Google Maps for Flutter and using Android devices. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/105965