# Attempt to read from null array com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.g.a only on Android 5.1

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I have a strange bug reported on Crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.g.a(g.java:56)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.drawable.ao.a(ao.java:91)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.store.fetch.i.a(i.java:99)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.store.fetch.f.a(f.java:3)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.store.j.a(j.java:19)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.store.k.a(k.java:96)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.store.k.d(k.java:178)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.store.k.a(k.java:31)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.store.f.handleMessage(f.java:100)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.store.k.run(k.java:126)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.store.ab.run(ab.java:12)
```

It happens only on some devices with Android 5 (Lenovo, Gigabyte, Acer...) 
Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59209714/google-maps-crash-java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-read-from-null-arr